# Oracle SQL with grouping returns nothing

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a problem.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(reg_date,'dd'),'DD.MM.YYYY') AS "DATE", 
       COUNT(*)
  FROM tablename
 WHERE reg_date >= TO_DATE('01.08.2013') AND 
       reg_date <= TO_DATE('28.08.2013')
GROUP BY TRUNC(reg_date,'dd')
```

In this query I'm counting amount of registered events at one date, but it returns zero with filled table.
What is the problem?

Comment: Are there any data in between '01.08.2013' and '28.08.2013'? i.e. what does "select * from tablename where reg_date >= To_Date('01.08.2013') and reg_date <= To_Date('28.08.2013')" return?

Comment: Probably not related, but you should supply a date format for the `to_date()` function. It makes your code more robust

Comment: I agree @a_horse_with_no_name - if the query isn't actually bombing then it's not related now, but it runs the risk of breaking in the future if the default date format is changed.

Comment: I am wondering why he has to use group by function here..... I am getting more of like not a group by expression....

Comment: @PingOfDeath - there's nothing to suggest a syntax or logic error in your query. Could you post the actual results, plus examples of a couple rows you think should have been included in the query? One tip: to make sure your `WHERE` clause always works use this instead: `WHERE reg_date >= DATE '2013-08-01' AND reg_date <= DATE '2013-08-08'`. That way you're using an Oracle (and ANSI) date constant that doesn't rely on your default date format settings.

Comment: @SarathiKamaraj: the use of the `count(*)` *requires* a `group by`

Comment: #a_horse_with_no_name am sorry i missed that count of *

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, yes there are a lot of data in that between. But when I'm using this query in Oracle SQL developer (ubuntu) it returns nothing.
In windows TOAD - works fine...

Comment: @PingOfDeath there is no error in your code

Comment: It may be this has something to do with the different default date formats in the 2 different products and their clients. Adding a date format to your to_date(), as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name, would at least eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Well, guy thank u a lot!
i changed my query and it works!:

    SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(scheme.table.reg_date,'dd'),'DD.MM.YYYY') AS "DATE", COUNT(*)
    FROM scheme.table
    WHERE scheme.table.reg_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.08.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') AND TO_DATE('28.08.2013','dd.mm.yyyy')
    GROUP BY TRUNC(scheme.table.reg_date,'dd');

And it works! I figured out that TOAD links current scheme and Oracle SQL developer - no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guys I did it!
i changed my query and it works:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(scheme.table.reg_date,'dd'),'DD.MM.YYYY') AS "DATE", COUNT(*)
FROM scheme.table
WHERE scheme.table.reg_date
BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.08.2013','dd.mm.yyyy') AND TO_DATE('28.08.2013','dd.mm.yyyy')
GROUP BY TRUNC(scheme.table.reg_date,'dd');
```

I figured out that TOAD is linking current scheme and Oracle SQL developer - no that is why I have to set schema directly